# После сборки приложения ELECTRON, не могу перезаписать данные локального JSON и подгрузить их обратно

Tags: node.js, electron

В json записываю данные, которые пользователь вводит в приложении. Из среды разработки все работает корректно, json перезаписывается и мы сразу видим обновленные данные в интерфейсе.

После сборки приложения для распространения, данные json либо не обновляются, либо не подгружаются. Может папку в которой лежит json-файл необходимо как-то особенно добавлять к проекту для финальной сборки?

```
ipc.on('get-default-data', (event) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'json', 'default.json'), (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            event.sender.send("new-default-data", JSON.parse(data));
        }
    });
});

ipc.on('get-user-data', (event) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'json', 'userSettingsData.json'), (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            event.sender.send("new-user-data", data.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

Я записал короткий видос для большей наглядности. Меняю заголовок на "1" сохраняем и в интерфейсе заголовок обновляется, закрываем и открываем приложение повторно, заголовок остается "1". Но тот же сценарий не работает в приложении после сборки. Ссылка на видео: https://yadi.sk/i/u-d8I7CvrFE41g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях мы выяснили, что есть два файла

- default.json с настройками приложения по умолчанию
- userSettingsData.json с пользовательскими настройками

Упаковщиком служит electron-builder.

Если приложение запускается из консоли то файл default.json будет браться локально, если же приложение запаковано то файл должен идти вместе с приложением (иначе откуда его брать)(не забудьте добавить его в конфиг билдера, например в files). Таким образом, для default.json делаем так:

```
const defaultjson = path.join(
  app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : __dirname,
  'json',
  'default.json'
);
```

В то же время, файл с пользовательскими данными и настройками можно хранить в [каталоге данных приложения](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname), который "свой собственный" для каждого пользователя. Пользовательские настройки будут одинаково доступны и при запуске dev-версии, и при запуске запакованного приложения.

```
const usersettingsdatajson = path.join(
  app.getPath('appData'),
  'userSettingsData.json'
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Протестировал. Из среды разработки и в собранной программе меняю заголовок на "1", сохраняю, но после перезапуска программы заголовок старый, значит обновленный файл не подгружается или не изменяется. Удивительно, когда вернул свой старый код, в среде разработки сразу подтянулся обновленный заголовочными - "1"

Comment: также попробовал вынести часть кода: const filepath = path.join(
  app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : __dirname,
  'json',
  'default.json'
); 
За пределы функции, результат был такой же. Файл не обновляется или не подгружается.

Comment: у кейсов "из среды разработки" и "в собранной программе" разные каталоги и разные файлы. т.е. правки "из среды разработки" будут видны при загрузке "из среды разработки", правки "в собранной программе" будут видны в "в собранной программе". если нужно чтобы и там, и там было одно хранилище то нужно использовать другую функцию

Comment: заменить всё вычисление базового каталога на `app.getPath('appData')`

Comment: То есть нужно заменить: 
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'json', 'default.json'), (err, data) => { ... на fs.readFile(app.getPath(__dirname, 'json', 'default.json'), (err, data) => {... ? 
Если не затруднит, напишите пример, пожалуйста

Comment: нет, `fs.readFile(path.join(app.getPath('appData'), 'default.json'), (err, data) => {`. файлы будут храниться отдельно от проекта в пользовательском пространстве. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname

Comment: Спасибо. Пойду переписывать, как я понял необходимо сначала создать эту директорию app.getPath('appData') и записать туда како-то дефолтный json, чтобы потом к нему обращаться и перезаписывать со стороны клиента.

Comment: если default.json будет лежать "в приложении" то обращаться к нему надо через `app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : __dirname`

Comment: но надо понимать, что это будут два разных default.json

Comment: @Alex изменил ответ по результатам общения в комментариях

Comment: спасибо тебе огромное, все получилось, потестил собранную программу на MAC OS - успех. Надеюсь на WIN будет все хорошо.

Comment: хорошо. пометь ответ принятым